# Perform a Case insensitive Like query in a case sensitive SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-like, collation, case-insensitive

This is my scenario.

SQL Server 2014 Standard edition, I have a database with a collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2` which is case sensitive.

I want to perform a `LIKE` query which should return the output irrespective of case sensitive.

Ex: if i execute a `Like` query to fetch the records with userName 'John' it should also return rows irrespective of case sensitive 'JOHN', 'John', 'john','joHN'.

I tried using `Lcase`, `Ucase`, but I am getting the error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
>   'LCASE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

This is my sample query

```
SELECT TOP 300 * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate
     FROM usertable 
     WHERE personid = 2 
       AND (Name LIKE LCASE('%john%')) 

     UNION 

     SELECT 
         userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate, 
     FROM usertable2 
     WHERE personid = 2 
       AND (Name LIKE LCASE( '%john%') OR Place LIKE LCASE('%NY%')) ) a 
ORDER BY 
    userNo
```

Guys help me out with your valuable suggestions , I am bit confused of using collation based DB.

Comment: SQL Server's functions to change a character value to upper or lower case actually called "UPPER" and "LOWER". ([List of string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181984.aspx).) You may be looking in the documentation for the wrong RDBMS...

Comment: @Matt Gibson  Thanks for pointing me out, i should have used the UPPER / LOWER.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`UPPER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180055.aspx) or [`LOWER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174400.aspx) functions to convert the values to the same case. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE UPPER(YourColumn) = UPPER('VALUE')
```

Alternatively, you can specify the collation manually when comparing:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn = 'VALUE' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

Comment: Like to know does your answer has any performance issue by converting a column value to `UPPER` or `LOWER` case then using the `LIKE` to search ?

Comment: @stom Of course there will always be a performance hit when calling functions. You can mitigate that with a persisted computed column though.

Comment: @DavidG ,Thanks, could you refer a article, on how to do computed column for case insensitive  search ?

Comment: Calling UPPER/LOWER should be slower especially for many rows. You need to test this though. It's an easy task. Also there's a difference between UPPER/LOWER and changing COLLATION. Changing collation performs character conversions (accent insensitive, ie. À becomes A) which case conversion DOES NOT!

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole Well, it depends on which collation you choose. You can choose case-sensitive which will treat `À` and `A` differently, or accent-sensitive which won't. The `_CI` and `_AI` parts of the collation tell you what it will do.

Comment: @DavidG, I thought that was implied, but true. Also I think you meant `"You can choose accent-insensitive which will treat À and A differently, or accent-sensitive which won't."`, in stead of `"You can choose case-sensitive which will treat À and A differently, or accent-sensitive which won't."`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using `lower()`, you need to apply it to the *column* not the pattern.  The pattern is already lower case.

```
Select  top 300 a.*
from (SELECT userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate
      FROM usertable 
      where personid = 2 and lower(Name) LIKE '%john%'
      UNION 
      SELECT userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate
      FROM usertable2 
      where personid = 2 and
            (lower(Name) like '%john%' or lower(Place) like '%ny%')
     ) a
order by userNo;
```

Note that `UNION ALL` is preferable to `UNION`, unless you intentionally want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax Is differ Over Different Db-Provider For Example:

> > select * from TABLE1 where upper(COL) like 'SOMETHING',, gives syntax error in ODCB Provider for Microsoft... and the right syntax is :
> > select * from TABLE1 where ucase(COL) like 'SOMETHING' ,, i.e. uppercase

So you should use the correct syntax used by your db provider

thanks

Answer (score -2):

use code below

SELECT TOP 300 * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate
     FROM usertable 
     WHERE personid = 2 
       AND (Name LIKE '%john%') 
     UNION

```
 SELECT 
     userNo, userName, Place, Birthdate, 
 FROM usertable2 
 WHERE personid = 2 
   AND (Name LIKE '%john%' OR Place LIKE '%NY%') a
```

ORDER BY 
    userNo