# Why some of the results for SQL query containing certain alphabets are missing?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-like

I have following table
[image]

When I run following query, it should have shown all instructor name containing 's' but it doesnot.
The query I've written:

```
SQL> SELECT instructor_name
  2  FROM instructor
  3  WHERE instructor_name LIKE '%s%';
```

The result is:

[image]

What is the problem here? Should not Balbir Silakar and Saurav Pangeni too must appear on the result?

Comment: Seems like a _case sensitive collation_ is used. Either specify a case insensitive collation, or use LOWER(), e.g. `WHERE lower(instructor_name) LIKE '%s%'`.

Comment: Looks like your table is created as case sensitive, ie `'s' <> 'S'`

Comment: you are looking for the "s" and technically "S" is something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'s'` and `'S'` are two different things if your column has a case-sensitive collation.

Alas, Oracle does not provide a case-insensitive version of `like` (usually called `ilike` in other databases).

You could do:

```
where instructor_name like '%s%' or instructor_name like '%S%'
```

Or:

```
where lower(instructor_name) like '%s%'
```

Or, you can use `regexp_like()`; it takes a third argument that can be used to make the search case insensitive.

```
where regexp_like(instructor_name, 's', 'i')
```

I would not be surprised that the regex would be the fastest option out of the three.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `s` (chr(115)) and `S` (chr(83)) are two different things, and there is no `s` in 'Balbir Silakar' or 'Saurav Pangeni'.

From Oracle 12.2 you can use

```
where instructor_name collate binary_ci like '%s%';
```

You can additionally ignore accents with

```
where instructor_name collate binary_ai like '%s%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database (by default I think) is case-sensitive, thus the LIKE matching mechanism is case-sensitive. Those names contain an upper-case S.

Here's a Q&A on how to make the search not case-sensitive. [Perform a Case insensitive Like query in a case sensitive SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213945/perform-a-case-insensitive-like-query-in-a-case-sensitive-sql-server-database)

Comment: Are you sure OP is using MS SQL Server? (I don't recognize the screen image.)

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive check use regexp_like

```
where regexp_like(instructor_name , 's', 'i');
```